# How to change GUI background color and icons?

Tags: raspbian, lxde, pixel, desktop

I want to change the default background color, and the image icons for folders, recycling bin, etc., in Raspbian's default GUI.

Comment: @TheOneWhoMade , just to get you started, try right clicking the taskbar and selecting "panel settings". And right click on the desktop and select "desktop preferences".

Comment: Okay, I edited the question to be properly scoped.  As a clue about this, what you are looking to configure is the [desktop environment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Desktop_environment) (DE).  GNU/Linux is heterogeneous this way, i.e., there are many possible DE's.  The one used by default on Raspbian is *PIXEL* (hence I added the tag above).  PIXEL is based on [LXDE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LXDE), and most of the documentation of  the latter should apply (since I believe PIXEL is largely undocumented).  Note you are also free to use a *different* DE if you find one you like.